# Placeholder in Jenkins Job - Build with Parameter

Tags: maven, jenkins

I need to stop an ear file whose name starts with PDIEEARModule-VersionNumber-SNAPSHOT.ear. So in the Build by Parameter value I need to mention explicitly the full ear name. Is it possible to provide PDIEEARModule[$] so that it picks up the ear, with whatever version it has, and stops the ear while build is in process?

[image]